# Can't remove markers with AngularJS Google Maps plugin and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, marker, ionic-framework

my html page renders the map by this:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
  <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'coords'" icon="'icon'" ></ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

And this is the controller:

```
angular.module('controllers.mapscontroller', [])

.controller("MapCtrl", function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, dataFactory) {

    $scope.POIs=[];
    $scope.markers = [];

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {

        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 40.3555013, longitude: 18.1573811 }, zoom: 8 };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            $scope.map = { center: { latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude }, zoom: 8 };
        });

        dataFactory.getPOIs("it-IT")
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.POIs=data.data.contents;
                $scope.initializePOIsOnMap();
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });

    $scope.removePOIs = function() {

        $scope.markers=[]; //<-- does nothing !!!
    };


    $scope.initializePOIsOnMap = function() {

        for(var POI in $scope.POIs) {

            var marker = {
              id: $scope.POIs[POI].id,
              coords: {
                latitude: $scope.POIs[POI].latitude,
                longitude: $scope.POIs[POI].longitude
              },
              options: { draggable: false , visible:true},
              icon: "img/catIcons/"+$scope.POIs[POI].catid+".png"
            };

            $scope.markers.push(marker);
        }
    }
});
```

Maps gets displayed correctly, and markers as well. 
But unfortunately, as you can read in $scope.removePOIs function, I can't remove the markers from the map. I've tried different solutions found over stackoverflow and the Web ($scope.markers.length=0, marker.setMap(null), ...) but no luck.

Any hint??
Thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!
The problem was that I specified the controller twice: in the app.js and in the HTML page. The reason for specifying it in the HTML page is that I use the switchery plugin, which requires the ng-controller attribute to be set in the  tag.
I removed the controller property from the app.js, putted all the HTML (the maps tags) within the  tag and now it works.
Thanks!
Roberto

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of deleting markers using angularjs:

[**Example**](https://ngmap.github.io/drawings.html)

Look at the script for remove markers example.

Comment: Thank you Larry. Unfortunately it seems to be another project's example page: https://ngmap.github.io/drawings.html . I use this: http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/